# Virtualbox Host only network stops working after a while in Corporate network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

We have a Win10 host running Virtualbox. We use a linux guest to run docker (docker Machine). The docker containers run a webapplication. The webapplication is used only from the LAN of the host system. (the host has a fixed ip address in the lan)

Within the lan of the host system you can access the webapp via the address of the host. This is done via port forwarding on a nat adapter of the guest system.
[image: vm box config]

This all works fine for several month in simple LAN setups (small office lan or home style lan) But in the corporate network of a customer the connection between host network and the vm stops working after a few hours. (When the corporate network is disconnected, the problem does not occur). But the vm is still running and the webapplication can be reached with the guest IP address from the host. But the vm containers in the vm can not reach the host anymore.

I am thinking that some security policies in the corporate network are causing this. But I am really not a network expert. Where would you start looking for a solution? (Is there any better more robust way to setup the networking to achieve the same goal?)

Comment: So is the VM using NAT networking or is it using 'host-only' networking, or both? (Also, why is this being hosted on VirtualBox and Win10 at all?)

Comment: The VM has host only network and a nat (the port forwarding is setup on the nat adapter). The win10 and VM setup is because of external requirements (I would have done it otherwise if possible). Docker desktop would now be a better solution but when we started docker desktop did not exist for windows.

Comment: Are there any overlaps between the corp network's addressing and either of the VM's interfaces? (e.g. does the host-only subnet conflict with something on the corp net?) Does the VM's routing table look the same before & after? (Does it still have the same default routes with the same metrics, etc.) Is the VM trying to access the host via "host-only" interface, or via "NAT" interface? (The former is more likely to have problems with security software on the host.) If the host has to be Windows-based, I'd say Hyper-V would be a more reliable option in general...

Comment: Thanks very much, I need to investigate that on the failing system. The VM is trying to reach the host via the NAT interface.

Comment: @user1686 now I got the results. On the VM the route -n shows all the different network adapters. when the system is in the "error" state... route -n shows, that the host network adapter is missing completely.

Comment: the routing tables remain the same.